# R - Getting Hourly Average from not constant frequency data acquisition

Tags: r

I have tons of meteorological data gathered from a Hobo station, which has it's own software, but is hard to post process it there. So, I just appended all the information in a descent data.frame but now I've been reading to learn how to get hourly results. Have tried with the Plyr and lubridate package with no succeed yet. I'm a novice programmer in R, usually building codes from patchs of work find on the internet.

So, What I already have is the following:

```
    data<-read.csv("file.txt",header=TRUE,sep=";",dec=".",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    data<-data[-1,]

    data$TIMETAMP <- strptime(data$TIMETAMP, format="%d-%m-%y %H:%M",         tz=Sys.timezone(location=TRUE))

    data$Vel_VIENTO<-as.numeric(as.character(data$Vel_VIENTO))
    data$Vel_RAFAGAS <-as.numeric(as.character(data$Vel_RAFAGAS))
    data$Temp_Amb <-as.numeric(as.character(data$Temp_Amb))

    data$HR <-as.numeric(as.character(data$HR))
    data$Temp_Agua <-as.numeric(as.character(data$Temp_Agua))
    data$Presion <-as.numeric(as.character(data$Presion))

    data$Radiacion <-as.numeric(as.character(data$Radiacion))
    data$Dir_VIENTO <-as.numeric(as.character(data$Dir_VIENTO))
```

the data looks like the following:

```
      REGISTRO               FECHA Vel_VIENTO Vel_RAFAGAS Temp_Amb   HR Temp_Agua
    2        1 2015-01-08 15:03:00       6.30        7.55   20.579 58.5    23.472
    3        2 2015-01-08 15:18:00       6.55        9.07   20.412 57.5    22.609
    4        3 2015-01-08 15:33:00       6.80        8.56   21.413 54.7    23.761
    5        4 2015-01-08 15:48:00       6.30        8.31   20.222 59.5    22.705
    6        5 2015-01-08 16:03:00       6.55        8.31   20.246 58.6    22.298
    7        6 2015-01-08 16:18:00       7.30        9.57   19.008 63.5    21.366
      Presion Radiacion Dir_VIENTO
    2  906.55        NA         NA
    3  906.15        NA         NA
    4  905.95        NA         NA
    5  906.05        NA      202.2
    6  906.05     966.9      210.6
    7  905.75     919.4      227.4
```

So each column has one parameter with a TIMESTAMP on data$TIMESTAMP. The frequency of the data ranges from every 15 mins to every 30 mins within the data.frame. I would like to get the same table with the hourly averages for each of the parameters in the data.frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function that I have been using for similar applications. The main things to watch out for are using trunc instead of round and that you need to convert datetime into POSIXct for dplyr and trunc returns POSIXlt.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

hourly_ave <- function(timeseries_data){

  # Convert the "FECHA" column into datetime
  timeseries_data$FECHA <- mdy_hm(timeseries_data$FECHA) 

  # Add an Hourly column (use trunc instead of round)
  # Remember the "as.POSIXct() since trunc() returns POSIXlt which dplyr does not support
  timeseries_data$Hourly = trunc(timeseries_data$FECHA, "hours") %>% as.POSIXct()

  # Then group the data and summarize using dplyr
  # I did not include all the variables, but you should get the idea
  data_hr <- timeseries_data %>% 
              group_by(Hourly) %>%
              summarize(Vel_RAFAGAS = mean(Vel_RAFAGAS), Temp_Am = mean(Temp_Am), HR = mean(HR), Temp_Ag = mean(Temp_Ag))

  data_hr 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all it would be great if you could (in the future) include a code snippet so we could provide you with a reproducable solution.

As one possible solution I would suggest to have a look at the dplyr package, have separate columns for the date, the time and the hour and finally group everything by date and hour to calculate the hourly mean:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
FECHA <- c("2015-01-08 15:03:00", "2015-01-08 15:18:00","2015-01-08 15:33:00","2015-01-08 15:48:00","2015-01-08 16:03:00","2015-01-08 16:18:00")
Temp_Aqua <- c("23.472","22.609", "23.761","22.705", "22.298", "21.366")
date_time <- matrix(unlist(str_split(FECHA, " ")), ncol = 2, byrow = T)
x <- as.data.frame(cbind(date_time, Temp_Aqua), stringsAsFactors = F)
names(x) <- c("date", "time", "temp_aqua")
x$temp_aqua <- as.numeric(x$temp_aqua)
x$hour <- str_extract(x$time, "^[0-9]{2}")
x %>% group_by(date, hour) %>% summarise(hourly_temp_aqua = mean(temp_aqua))

Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
Groups: date [?]

        date  hour hourly_temp_aqua
       <chr> <chr>            <dbl>
1 2015-01-08    15         23.13675
2 2015-01-08    16         21.83200
```

In your solution you should have the timestamp correctly stored/formatted and potentially consider whether the simple mean is the right solution (e.g., if the intervalls are not equally distributed you could consider giving them a different weight)

Hope this helps!